# Rich Faces: Is it possible to set the look of output text like input type password?

Tags: css, richfaces

We have a list of attributes in a dataTable. Some of these attributes are outputtext fields (passwords) (Password fields are usually shown as list of black bullets if they are input fields (inputSecret)). At the moment the outputText fields are shown as plain text which has not much sense. It is possible to let them look like password input fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
<h:outputText value="&bull;&bull;&bull;&bull;&bull;&bull;&bull;&bull;" rendered="#{[WHEN FIELD IS A PASSWORD FIELD}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with CSS, if you want a password input, the type is `password` and not `text`

I don't know much about richFaces, but maybe you need  `<h:inputSecret />` instead of  `<h:inputText />`

Comment: My question was unclear. I need output fields look like input fields (actually like inputSecret fields).